# Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by InputMask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I Created a logic in my react app to display an error string when an empty field was detected in any input.

One of these fields has a mask and I used the component "InputMask" from the lib "react-input-mask"

**The problem**: I use RTL to test my empty field logic but when I use the InputMask component I have this error:

```
 console.error
    Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by InputMask. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks
    
       Previous render            Next render
       ------------------------------------------------------
    1. useRef                     useRef
    2. useRef                     useEffect
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
        in InputMask (created by GeneralInformationView)
        in ThemeProvider (created by DesignTokensProvider)
        in DesignTokensProvider (created by GeneralInformationView)
        in GeneralInformationView (created by GeneralInformation)
        in GeneralInformation

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:5)
      at warnOnHookMismatchInDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14715:9)
      at updateHookTypesDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14674:9)
      at Object.useEffect (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15900:7)
      at Object.useEffect (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1509:21)

  console.error
    Warning: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.
    
    Previous: []
    Incoming: [function () {
        // If there are simulated focus events, runLoop could be
        // called multiple times without blur or re-render
        if (deferIdRef.current !== null) {
          return;
        }
    
        function loop() {
          callback();
          deferIdRef.current = defer(loop);
        }
    
        loop();
      }, function () {
        cancelDefer(deferIdRef.current);
        deferIdRef.current = null;
      }]
        in InputMask (created by GeneralInformationView)
        in ThemeProvider (created by DesignTokensProvider)
        in DesignTokensProvider (created by GeneralInformationView)
        in GeneralInformationView (created by GeneralInformation)
        in GeneralInformation

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:5)
      at areHookInputsEqual (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14749:7)
      at updateEffectImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15313:11)
      at updateEffect (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15343:10)
      at Object.useEffect (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15901:14)
      at Object.useEffect (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1509:21)
```

My components:

**GeneralInformationView**

```
export const GeneralInformationView = ({
  onChangeField,
  hasFieldsError
}: IGeneralInformationViewProps): JSX.Element => {
  const INPUT_WIDTH = 800;

  return (
    <DesignTokensProvider>
      <InputRegistration
        id="legalName"
        name="legalName"
        label="Legal name"
        aria-label="Legal name"
        placeholder="Enter legal name"
        onChange={onChangeField}
        hasError={hasFieldsError.legalName.hasError}
        errorText={hasFieldsError.legalName.errorMessage}
        width={INPUT_WIDTH}
      />
      <InputRegistration
        id="tradeName"
        name="tradeName"
        label="Trade name"
        aria-label="Trade name"
        placeholder="Enter trade name"
        onChange={onChangeField}
        hasError={hasFieldsError.tradeName.hasError}
        errorText={hasFieldsError.tradeName.errorMessage}
        width={INPUT_WIDTH}
      />
      <InputMask mask="999-99999-9" onChange={onChangeField}>
        <InputRegistration
          id="governmentId"
          name="governmentId"
          label="Government ID"
          placeholder="Enter government ID"
          hasError={hasFieldsError.governmentId.hasError}
          errorText={hasFieldsError.governmentId.errorMessage}
          width={INPUT_WIDTH}
        />
      </InputMask>
    </DesignTokensProvider>
  );
};
```

**GeneralInformation**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { GeneralInformationView } from './GeneralInformationView';
import { IGeneralInformationErrors } from './GeneralInformation.d';

const hasFieldsErrorObject: IGeneralInformationErrors = {
  legalName: { hasError: false, errorMessage: '' },
  tradeName: { hasError: false, errorMessage: '' },
  governmentId: { hasError: false, errorMessage: '' }
};

const fieldsValidator = (value: string) => {
  const EMPTY_MESSAGE = 'This field is required.';

  let errorObject = { hasError: false, errorMessage: '' };

  if (value === '') {
    errorObject = { hasError: true, errorMessage: EMPTY_MESSAGE };
  }

  return errorObject;
};

export const GeneralInformation = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [hasFieldsError, setHasFieldsError] = useState(hasFieldsErrorObject);

  const onChangeField = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setHasFieldsError({
      ...hasFieldsError,
      [name]: fieldsValidator(value)
    });
  };

  return <GeneralInformationView onChangeField={onChangeField} hasFieldsError={hasFieldsError} />;
};
```

And finally my test file
**GeneralInformation.test**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

import { GeneralInformation } from './GeneralInformation';

const changeFieldValue = (targetElement: HTMLElement, newValue: unknown) => {
  fireEvent.change(targetElement, { target: { value: newValue } });
};

const getFieldByRole = (role: string, option = {}) => {
  return screen.getByRole(role, option);
};

describe('GeneralInformation', () => {
  describe('show field error message', () => {
    it('when field Legal name as empty', () => {
      render(<GeneralInformation />);

      const input = getFieldByRole('textbox', { name: 'Legal name' });

      changeFieldValue(input, 'Teste');
      changeFieldValue(input, '');

      expect(screen.getByText('This field is required.')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to show us the code for `InputMask`. The error suggests you're using a hook wrong (in an inner function, or in a conditional)

Comment: InputMask is a component of the lib "react-input-mask", I did not implement this component in my application

Comment: @noé Did you read the documentation for the library? You not using it as they say you should...

Comment: @super I see the documentation and I pick where they say is the right form:

<InputMask mask="99/99/9999" value={props.value} onChange {props.onChange}>
      <MaterialInput type="tel" disableUnderline />
</InputMask>

Only the field value in my case isn't passed because the field doesn't start with an initial value.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: @noé Yes, you missed the fact that it's a render function, and not a component being passed as a child. `<InputMask>{(props) => <MaterialInput ... />}</InputMask>`. That's not a detail you can just leave out.

Comment: @super I change the implementation to use in this form, but not work and displays this error: `Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' of type 'function' supplied to 'InputMask', expected a single ReactElement.`